# why does a particular line is not executing in the given code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, queue

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self,max_size):
        self.__max_size=max_size
        self.__elements=[None]*self.__max_size
        self.__rear=-1
        self.__front=0

    def is_full(self):
        if(self.__rear==self.__max_size-1):
                return True
        return False

    def is_empty(self):
        if(self.__front>self.__rear):
            return True
        return False

    def enqueue(self,data):
        if(self.is_full()):
            print("Queue is full!!!")
        else:
            self.__rear+=1
            self.__elements[self.__rear]=data

    def dequeue(self):
        if(self.is_empty()):
            print("Queue is empty!!!")
        else:
            data=self.__elements[self.__front]
            self.__front+=1
            return data

    def display(self):
        for index in range(self.__front, self.__rear+1):
            print(self.__elements[index])

    def get_max_size(self):
        return self.__max_size

    #You can use the below __str__() to print the elements of the DS object while debugging
    def __str__(self):
        msg=[]
        index=self.__front
        while(index<=self.__rear):
            msg.append((str)(self.__elements[index]))
            index+=1
        msg=" ".join(msg)
        msg="Queue data(Front to Rear): "+msg
        return msg

class Stack:
    def __init__(self,max_size):
        self.__max_size=max_size
        self.__elements=[None]*self.__max_size
        self.__top=-1

    def is_full(self):
        if(self.__top==self.__max_size-1):
            return True
        return False

    def is_empty(self):
        if(self.__top==-1):
            return True
        return False

    def push(self,data):
        if(self.is_full()):
            print("The stack is full!!")
        else:
            self.__top+=1
            self.__elements[self.__top]=data

    def pop(self):
        if(self.is_empty()):
            print("The stack is empty!!")
        else:
            data= self.__elements[self.__top]
            self.__top-=1
            return data

    def display(self):
        if(self.is_empty()):
            print("The stack is empty")
        else:
            index=self.__top
            while(index>=0):
                print(self.__elements[index])
                index-=1

    def get_max_size(self):
        return self.__max_size

    #You can use the below __str__() to print the elements of the DS object while debugging
    def __str__(self):
        msg=[]
        index=self.__top
        while(index>=0):
            msg.append((str)(self.__elements[index]))
            index-=1
        msg=" ".join(msg)
        msg="Stack data(Top to Bottom): "+msg
        return msg    


def queue_ordering(input_queue,input_stack):
    output_queue=Queue(input_queue.get_max_size())
    while not input_stack.is_empty():
        n = input_stack.pop()
        if(n==1):
            c = input_queue.dequeue()
            input_queue.enqueue(c) 'This line is not getting executed'
        elif(n==2):
            list1 = []
            while not input_queue.is_empty():
                c = input_queue.dequeue()
                list1.append(c)
            m = len(list1)
            temp = list1.pop(m-1)
            list1.insert(0,temp)
            for c in list1:
                input_queue.enqueue(c)
    output_queue = input_queue.copy()


    return output_queue


input_stack=Stack(5)
input_stack.push(1)
input_stack.push(2)
input_stack.push(1)
input_stack.push(1)
input_stack.push(1)

input_queue=Queue(3)
input_queue.enqueue('A')
input_queue.enqueue('C')
input_queue.enqueue('B')
output_queue=queue_ordering(input_queue, input_stack)
output_queue.display()
```

In the **queue_ordering** function when n=1, first element in queue should become last element and when n=2, last element should become first element. Since the mentioned line is not executing my queue gets emptied and therefore  i get an error. What is wrong in that function? No changes should be made in queue and stack classes.

Comment: Is this homework assignment? If so please state clearly the question and that the provided classes are provided by the instructions. Also what is the desired output?

Comment: When I run your code it does execute that statement you say is not executing. Your error must be somewhere else.